# Relocating a div with JS

Tags: javascript, html

Is there a way to relocate a div using JS, in order to have the most relevant copy in the HTML further up the page. But having the flexibility to display the same copy where ever you like, when it comes to what the end user sees? ie...

HTML:

```
<div id="three">Three(to be at the top of HTML but display at bottom in browser)</div>
<div id="one">One</div>
<div id="two">Two</div>
```

Browser:

```
One
Two 
Three(to be at the top of HTML but display at bottom in browser)
```

Is there a tutorial anywhere for this, and what function do I need to use? Thanks.

Comment: Out of interest why would you want to do this? Also, when do you want this to happen? One the click of a button? mouse over? What would be the trigger?

Comment: I am doing this to retain a sites good SEO. 'Three' will contain all the sites original home page copy, and 'One' and 'Two' will contain the new copy that is better for the user to read, but will lessen the good SEO of the site if they are at the top of the HTML.

Comment: Here is the HTML/CSS incase it might help to explain what I'd like to do - http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this kind of javascript to modify the CSS properties. To take the same idea as the one of the user named Safari, we can come up with this kind of code:

```
<script>
  document.getElementById('three').style.position = 'fixed';
  document.getElementById('three').style.bottom = 0;
</script>
```

Comment: I would like the 'Why Bother' box at the top of the right content to be displayed underneath 'Situational Judgement' at the bottom?

Answer (score 0):

Write this in your CSS, there is no JS needed:

```
#three {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: 'Why Bother' has moved to the very bottom. What do I need to add to keep it within the container? Thank again.

Comment: you have to set in the container element the position to absolute or relative.

Comment: Thanks. I've set: .contentCopyHalfBoxHome {position:relative;}. It is still the same?

Comment: if this is the parent node. then this will work. i advise you to check the matrix in google chrome webinspector (f12 tools)

Comment: I've tried adding this to all the parent elements just in case and it still doesn't keep it within the container?

Comment: i prepared you a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RXA3Q/4/) . have a look at it. and if you want to have the blue rectangle to be at the bottom of the browser then set the position of the blue rectangle to fixed. if you want to have it at the bottom of the container then to absolute.

Comment: Thank you so much. Is there a way to use relative instead of absolute? As using absolute does not allow the expandable elements to function properly? http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/.

Comment: sure. just use relative instead of absolute.

Comment: I have tried doing this but 'Why Bother' appears back up the top again? http://dev.assessmentday.co.uk/

Comment: Hi, does anyone know how to get this working with my expandable panels?